# Deploying an app on Google Cloud Platform - ImportError for pyzbar

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying an app with Flask that uses the library `pyzbar` (and more specifically the function `pyzbar.pyzbar.decode`)

It works perfectly on my machine; but when I deploy it, I have the error: `ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library`.

This is because [pyzbar.pyzbar runs](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/blob/master/pyzbar/zbar_library.py) `find_library('zbar')` (`find_library` is from [ctypes.util](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)) and nothing is returned.

Do you know what I should do?

Comment: can you share your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 1):

Create this files `app.yaml, main.py, requirements.txt`:

1.`app.yaml`

```
runtime: python37
```

2.`requirements.txt`

```
Flask==1.1.1
pyzbar
```

3.`main.py`

```
# [START gae_python37_app]
from flask import Flask
import pyzbar

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
   """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
   return 'Hello World!'
```

Then:

```
gcloud app deploy -q
gcloud app browse

#Hello Word
```

Everything worked as expected!

Comment: from pyzbar import pyzbar does not work ("ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library"). Though, I need the function pyzbar.pyzbar.decode.

Answer (score 0):

The lib-zbar-dev OS package is not present in the  App Engine standard environment and cannot be installed, even if pyzbar is installed. I suggest that you try to use an App Engine flexible custom runtime to install all necessary operating system dependencies. App Engine Flex offers a high level of customization, as this solution uses Debian-based docked images to run your applications.

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/customizing-the-python-runtime) you can find more information on how to create a custom runtime for App Engine Flex, keep in mind that you need to know Docker.

Another alternative is to use a [Compute Engine VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute) to run your application, this is not a serverless solution, but you can install all the necessary software for your application.